# Unpinning Deleted Folder from Quick Access

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-quick-access

I had a folder that I had pinned to my quick access and that folder has now been deleted. It is still pinned under my quick access but I cannot seem to get rid of it. I tried clearing the File Explorer History and that did nothing. I also tried following all of the steps in [this article](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-quick-access-reset-pinned-shortcuts-stuck-not-working-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Click%20Quick%20access.,choose%20Unpin%20from%20Quick%20access.) but nothing has worked. Is there any way to get this folder out of the way?
I have Windows 10. Is it possible that onedrive has something to do with it? (just a thought, I'm clearly no expert haha)

Update: When following step 4 of the article, I do not have a folder titled Microsoft. I am not sure if this is because an update and/or the article is dated, but the last step no matter what I did I could not find an Automatic Destinations folder in File Explorer. Is there another place this could be, or is it possibly called something else?

Update #2: I tried step 4 again, and it seems to have worked this time. How weird technology can be.

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: If you actually followed those instructions it’s literally not possible for any quick access entries to exist.

Comment: Please list ALL of the precise steps you followed. It should not be necessary to follow and read a link and then guess what parts of it you may or may not have followed, in order to know what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Ramhound I have followed the first three steps with no success. I had an issue with step four, which I will update my post on what I saw.